# Qual a diferença entre os relacionamentos entre tabelas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, relacionamento

Sei que existem três tipos de relacionamentos entre dados de diferentes tabelas:

- 1 : 1 (um para um);
- 1 : N (um para vários) ;
- N : N (vários para vários);

Mas qual seria a diferença entre os tipos de relacionamento e sua utilização em um banco de dados relacional?

Answer (score 17):

Isso é chamado [cardinalidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)).

De uma certa forma o que está na pergunta praticamente já diz o que é cada um.

**1:1** significa que para cada linha de uma tabela será referenciada em uma linha na outra tabela e vice-versa.

[image: um pra um][image: um pra um]

**1:N** significa que para cada linha em uma tabela será referenciada diversas linhas na outra tabela que por sua vez cada linha só pode ter uma linha referenciada na primeira tabela. Em geral pode ser de 0 à N linhas.

[image: um pra muitos][image: um pra muitos]

**M:N** significa que para cada linha em uma tabela será referenciada diversas linhas na outra tabela e esta última pode ter em cada uma de suas linhas diversas referências para a primeira tabela. Em geral pode ser de 0 à N linhas.

[image: muitos pra muitos][image: muitos pra muitos]

Não gosto desse N:N. Isto implica que ambos possuem o mesmo número, o que não costuma ser verdade. Sei que muita gente usa assim, mas prefiro M:N.

Usa-se também, 0..1, 0..* ou 1..* para indicar com mais precisão quantas linhas podem ser referenciadas no mínimo (antes dos pontos) e no máximo (depois dos pontos) indicando se nenhuma pode ser (0), deve ser uma (1) ou pode ser várias (*).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Avacalhando o seu `1:1`: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_pa%C3%ADses_com_m%C3%BAltiplas_capitais, tem também Nauru, que não tem capital, e a Suíça, em que a capital excepcionalmente não é estabelecida por lei, então tem e não tem. :D

Comment: A capital de Nauru é Yaren, sou especialista no país. É sério! https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nauru/@-0.5268213,166.924703,7721m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x6f7d1c1f1de45b4d:0x59d99df4c5d40a81!8m2!3d-0.522778!4d166.931503

Comment: _"Sua cidade mais populosa é Yaren, sendo também a casa do parlamento nacional, do único aeroporto da ilha e grande parte dos serviços governamentais. Então porque não se estabelece Yaren como capital? Porque a sede do poder executivo neste país situa-se num outro distrito, Meneng, pelo que, por agora, este país irá continuar sem qualquer capital."_ (oficialmente declarada pelo menos). https://culturadealgibeira.wordpress.com/2018/07/13/os-dois-paises-sem-capital/

Comment: E onde está a oficialidade disso?