# Como fazer chaves estrangeiras um-para-muitos usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tabela com 3 colunas:

```
  noticias   | categorias | tags
-----------------------------------------------
     id      |     id     | tag_a
noticia_nome |  tag_nome  | tag_b
 noticia_id  |            |  ...
             |            | tag_j (10 no total)
```

A coluna `tags` tem 10 tags, e eu tenho uma noticia que irá usar 4 tags como eu faço uma chave estrangeira (*foreign key*), para ligar o `noticia_id` com 4 tags?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/146432/57801

Comment: A tabela tags possui 10 coluna? Por quê? E se uma notícia pode possuir 4 tags e uma tag pode ser possuída por várias notícias, a relação será de muitos para muitos, não um para muitos.

Answer (score 1):

Você está confundindo o conceito de coluna com o conceito de tabela.

Observe essa sua tabela:

```
  noticias   | categorias | tags
-----------------------------------------------
     id      |     id     | tag_a
noticia_nome |  tag_nome  | tag_b
 noticia_id  |            | tag_c
             |            | tag_d
             |            | tag_e
             |            | tag_f
             |            | tag_g
             |            | tag_h
             |            | tag_i
             |            | tag_j
```

Nesta tabela, as linhas não são coisas que tenham muito significado lógico. O que você quer é trabalhar com três tabelas diferentes.

Vejamos como organizar essas tabelas:

- Uma notícia é uma coisa que tem um nome e um id. Não é permitido que duas notícias diferentes tenham o mesmo nome.
- Uma tag é uma coisa que tem um nome e um id. Não é permitido que duas tags diferentes tenham o mesmo nome.
- Você quer categorizar notícias ao colocar tags nelas. Uma notícia pode ter várias tags distintas. Uma mesma tag pode aparecer em várias notícias diferentes. Ou seja, isso é um relacionamento **muitos-para-muitos**, ou também chamado de M-para-N (ou N-para-N). Não é um relacionamento um-para-muitos como está na sua pergunta. Nota-se também que uma mesma tag não pode aparecer mais de uma vez na mesma notícia e nem uma mesma notícia pode aparecer mais de uma vez em uma mesma tag.

Assim, as suas tabelas ficam desse jeito:

```sql
CREATE TABLE noticia (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY pk_noticia (id),
    UNIQUE KEY noticia_nome (nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE tag (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY pk_tag (id),
    UNIQUE KEY tag_nome (nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE noticia_tag (
    id_noticia int(11) NOT NULL,
    id_tag int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY pk_noticia_tag (id_noticia, id_tag)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE noticia_tag ADD CONSTRAINT fk_noticia_tag_noticia FOREIGN KEY (noticia_id) REFERENCES noticia(id);
ALTER TABLE noticia_tag ADD CONSTRAINT fk_noticia_tag_tag FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id);
CREATE INDEX idx_noticia_tag_noticia ON noticia_tag (id_noticia);
CREATE INDEX idx_noticia_tag_tag ON noticia_tag (id_tag);
```

Para entender esse script, vamos fazer algumas observações:

- A instrução `CREATE TABLE` é a responsável por criar uma tabela, especificando nela, dentro dos parênteses, quais são as colunas.
- Cada coluna na instrução `CREATE TABLE` começa com o nome da coluna e com o tipo (aqui usamos os tipos `int(11)` e `varchar(50)`). Depois do tipo da coluna, podem ser acrescentados modificadores. Os modificadores que usamos aqui são `NOT NULL` e `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- O `AUTO_INCREMENT` diz que o valor da coluna será preenchido automaticamente pelo banco de dados quando ocorrer uma inserção.
- O `NOT NULL` diz que o valor da coluna não pode nunca ser `NULL`.
- As linhas do tipo `PRIMARY KEY pk_tabela (id)` dizem que o campo `id` é a chave primária em cada uma dessas tabelas. No caso de uma chave primária composta, há mais do que um campo dentro desses parênteses no `PRIMARY KEY`, tal como no `PRIMARY KEY pk_notica_tag (id_noticia, id_tag)`.
- Nas linhas do tipo `PRIMARY KEY`, esse nome que aparece entre a palavra `KEY` e o abre-parêntese é o nome da chave primária. Você não precisa especificar isso se não quiser, podendo usar apenas `PRIMARY KEY (id)` se preferir. Entretanto, se você não der um nome para a sua chave primária, o banco de dados vai dar o nome `PRIMARY` automaticamente.
- As linhas do tipo `UNIQUE KEY` têm um formato parecido com a da `PRIMARY KEY` e servem para especificar quais conjuntos de colunas não podem ser repetidos mesmo não sendo elas as chaves primárias. Cada chave única pode ter um nome, e se você não especificar um nome, o banco de dados vai inventar um nome sozinho com base no nome das colunas escolhidas (mas nem sempre o nome inventado será um bom nome).
- Para relacionar quais notícias têm quais tags, usamos a tabela `noticia_tag`. Essa tabela não contém nada mais além de linhas que casam uma notícia com uma tag. Uma mesma notícia pode aparecer várias vezes, e uma mesma tag também. Entretanto, uma mesma notícia com uma mesma tag só pode aparecer uma vez nesta tabela, uma vez que essa é a chave primária da tabela.
- O MySQL têm várias *engines* diferentes, que são formas distintas de se armazenar tabelas. Para cada tabela estamos usando a *engine* InnoDB. Isso é feito ao utilizar-se `ENGINE=InnoDB` após o fecha-perêntese de cada `CREATE TABLE`. O [MySQL têm várias *engines* diferentes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html).
- Para evitar problemas de *encoding*, utilizamos UTF-8 para a codificação de textos. É isso o que o `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` em cada instrução `CREATE TABLE` quer dizer.
- As instruções `ALTER TABLE` adicionam as chaves estrangeiras. É possível adicioná-las diretamente no `CREATE TABLE` também, mas prefiro fazer com `ALTER TABLE` porque assim você pode colocar todas as instruções `ALTER TABLE` no final do script de criação do banco de dados e com isso não precisa se preocupar com a ordem na qual as tabelas são criadas.
- As instruções `CREATE INDEX`, como o nome já diz, criam índices. Um índice serve para acelerar a busca em uma tabela, evitando-se que essa tenha que ser percorrida linha por linha quando uma busca for realizada. São criados dois índices na tabela `pk_notica_tag`. Um deles indexa pelo `id_tag`, e serve para achar rapidamente todas as notícias com uma determinada tag. O outro indexa pelo `id_noticia`, servindo para achar rapidamente todas as tags existentes em uma determinada notícia.

Answer (score -1):

Diz a sua instancia de conexão com o banco para fazer isso mais substitua os meus dados pelos seus

```
CREATE TABLE `cidades` (

`codcidade` INT NOT NULL ,
`descricao` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL

) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE `clientes` (

`codcliente` INT PRIMARY KEY ,
`nome` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL

) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE `vendedores` (

`codvendedor` INT PRIMARY KEY ,
`nome` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL

) ENGINE = innodb;

CREATE TABLE `vendas` (

`codvenda` INT PRIMARY KEY ,
`datavenda` DATE NOT NULL

`codcliente` INT,
`codvendedor` INT

) ENGINE = innodb;


ALTER TABLE `clientes` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_cidade` FOREIGN KEY ( `codcidade` ) REFERENCES `cidade` ( `codcidade` ) ;

ALTER TABLE `vendas` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_vendas_codcliente` FOREIGN KEY ( `codcliente` ) REFERENCES `clientes` ( ` codcliente ` ) ;

ALTER TABLE `vendas` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_vendas_codvendedor` FOREIGN KEY ( `codvendedor` ) REFERENCES `vendedores` ( ` codvendedor ` ) ;
```

Comment: Mas isso não chega nem perto do que ele/ela quer.

Comment: responde então oque ele quer

Comment: Já coloquei o que deve ser visto no meu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218986/como-fazer-foreigh-keys-um-para-muitos-usando-php/218995?noredirect=1#comment449326_218986)... primeiramente o que está sendo solicitado uma relação de M pra N, como sua resposta não responde a esse quesito, eu lhe alertei.....

Comment: valeu aii Everson não tinha reparado

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que o seu código faz?