# Diferenças @OneToMany, @ManyToMany, @ManyToOne, @OneToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Queria montar um banco de dados com o Java Hibernate como o abaixo:

[image: Desenho do Banco]

Dúvidas:

- Qual a diferença entre `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne`? E como seria sua declaração no Java? Exemplo, tem que ser `List<Objeto>`.
- Estou pensando em utilizar o `@OneToOne`, um exemplo na avaliação, o usuário estaria bloqueado de realizar uma nova avaliação?

Comment: Eu acho que segue o mesmo conceito: [Qual a diferença entre os relacionamentos entre tabelas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146425/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-relacionamentos-entre-tabelas)

Comment: A maneira que outros posts explicaram eu não consegui entender, mas como o cara abaixo explicou, eu consegui.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Mapeamentos unidirecionais vs bidirecionais

Antes de tudo, é preciso notar-se que cada um dos relacionamentos `@OneToOne`,  `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` e `@ManyToMany` pode ser unidirecional ou bidirecional.

No relacionamento unidirecional entre duas entidades A e B, partindo-se da entidade A, eu chego facilmente a uma instância da entidade B, mas não consigo facilmente fazer o caminho contrário.

Já no relacionamento bidirecional, eu também posso a partir da entidade B, facilmente navegar de volta para a entidade A.

## Mapeamento `@ManyToOne` unidirecional

O `@ManyToOne` significa muitos-para-1. Neste seu exemplo (vou supor que o campo `categoria` na tabela `evento` deveria se chamar `categoria_id`), teríamos isso:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
public class Evento {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id")
    private Categoria categoria;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
}
```

O lado `Many` é o da classe que envolve isso tudo, no caso `Evento`. O lado `One` é o da entidade relacionada, no caso `Categoria`. Ou seja, muitos eventos para uma categoria. A mesma regra se aplica também ao `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToOne` e `@ManyToMany` (veremos mais sobre eles abaixo).

Isso acontece porque um evento tem apenas uma categoria, mas uma categoria pode ter muitos eventos. Com esse mapeamento, podemos fazer isso:

```
Evento e = ...;
Categoria c = e.getCategoria();
```

## Mapeamento `@OneToMany` unidirecional

O `@OneToMany` é o oposto do que o `@ManyToOne`, ou seja é o 1-para-muitos. Por exemplo, poderíamos fazer isso:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id") // Esta coluna está na tabela "evento".
    private List<Evento> eventos;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public List<Evento> getEventos() {
        return eventos;
    }
}
```

Com esse mapeamento, podemos fazer isso:

```
Categoria c = ...;
List<Evento> eventos = c.getEventos();
```

## Mapeamentos `@OneToMany` e `@ManyToOne` bidirecionais

Se você tiver os dois casos acima ao mesmo tempo, onde a partir de `Evento` eu chego em categoria e a partir de `Categoria` eu chego em `Evento`, o resultado vai ser que o mapeamento vai dar errado. Por quê? Porque o JPA verá dois mapeamentos distintos, um deles de `Evento` para `Categoria` e um outro mapeamento diferente de `Categoria` para `Evento`. Ocorre que esses dois mapeamentos são um só!

É aí que entra o campo `mappedBy`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "evento")
public class Evento {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoria_id")
    private Categoria categoria;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public Categoria getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria")
    private List<Evento> eventos;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public List<Evento> getEventos() {
        return eventos;
    }
}
```

Nesta relação bidirecional, o `mappedBy` diz que o outro lado da relação que é o dono dela e que o campo que a modela é o de nome `categoria`. Observe que esse é o nome do campo da classe Java, e não o nome do campo no banco de dados!

Em geral, é recomendável que o lado da relação que termine com o `toOne` seja o dono da relação.

É importante em relacionamentos bidirecionais, sempre ligar os dois lados da relação antes de persistir no `EntityManager`:

```
Evento e = ...;
Categoria c = ...;
e.setCategoria(c);
c.eventos.add(e);
```

## Mapeamento `@OneToOne`

Se você usar o `@OneToOne` você modela o caso 1-para-1. Você pode fazer com que uma avaliação pertença a apenas uma pessoa, mas nesse tipo de relacionamento, você também tem que uma pessoa só pode ter uma avaliação.

Você faria isso assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avaliacao")
public class Avaliacao {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "pessoa_id")
    private Pessoa pessoa;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public Pessoa getPessoa() {
        return pessoa;
    }
}
```

Com isso, você pode fazer isso:

```
Avaliacao a = ...;
Pessoa avaliado = a.getPessoa();
```

Para fazer o contrário, é necessário que o relacionamento seja bidirecional:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pessoa")
    private Avaliacao avaliacao;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public Avaliacao getAvaliacao() {
        return avaliacao;
    }
}
```

E então, tendo o relacionamento bidirecional:

```
Pessoa p = ...;
Avaliacao a = p.getAvaliacao();
```

Novamente, no caso de relacionamentos bidirecionais, sempre deve-se ligar os dois lados da relação antes de persistir no `EntityManager`:

```
Pessoa p = ...;
Avaliacao a = ...;
a.setPessoa(p);
p.setAvaliacao(a);
```

## Mapeamento `@ManyToMany`

O seu diagrama não tem nenhum caso onde um relacionamento muitos-para-muitos exista. Então vamos bolar um:

> Um tipo de pizza têm vários tipos de ingredientes.
> Um tipo de ingrediente pode fazer parte de vários tipos de pizza.

E vamos supor que tenhamos a tabela `pizza`, a tabela `ingrediente` e uma tabela intermediária `pizza_ingrediente`, onde cada linha contém a chave das outras duas tabelas.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pizza")
public class Pizza {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "pizza_ingrediente",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pizza_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingrediente_id"),
    )
    private List<Ingrediente> ingredientes;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public List<Ingrediente> getIngredientes() {
        return ingredientes;
    }
}
```

A anotação `@JoinTable` é responsável por fazer o mapeamento da tabela intermediária. O `joinColumns` representa o lado da entidade que é dona do relacionamento (`Pizza`) e o `inverseJoinColumns` o lado da entidade relacionada (`Ingrediente`). Com isso tudo, é possível então fazer-se isso:

```
Pizza p = ...;
List<Ingrediente> ingredientes = p.getIngredientes();
```

Para fazer o relacionamento bidirecional, novamente temos o `mappedBy`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingrediente")
public class Ingrediente {

    // ... Outros campos ...

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredientes")
    private List<Pizza> pizzas;

    // ... Outros campos e métodos ...

    public List<Pizza> getPizzas() {
        return pizzas;
    }
}
```

E então podemos fazer isso também:

```
Ingrediente i = ...;
List<Pizza> pizzas = i.getPizzas();
```

E novamente, temos que lembrar de relacionar os dois lados:

```
Ingrediente mussarela = ...;
Ingrediente tomate = ...;
Ingrediente presunto = ...;
Ingrediente ovo = ...;

Pizza napolitana = ...;
Pizza portuguesa = ...;

napolitana.ingredientes.add(mussarela);
napolitana.ingredientes.add(tomate);
napolitana.ingredientes.add(presunto);

portuguesa.ingredientes.add(mussarela);
portuguesa.ingredientes.add(ovo);
portuguesa.ingredientes.add(presunto);

mussarela.pizzas.add(napolitana);
mussarela.pizzas.add(portuguesa);

presunto.pizzas.add(napolitana);
presunto.pizzas.add(portuguesa);

tomate.pizzas.add(napolitana);

ovo.pizzas.add(portuguesa);
```

Finalmente lembre-se disso:

> Se o relacionamento termina com `ToMany`, então você tem uma lista de entidades relacionadas. Se termina com `ToOne`, só há uma única entidade relacionada.

Comment: No caso de Avaliacao, se eu coloco apenas um OneToMany funciona normalmente, mas no caso de eu colocar um OneToMany para Evento e Pessoa, sendo que a primeira diz que precisa ser de uma List, e se coloco dentro, não aparece erro nenhum

Comment: @FelipeJunges Na hora que eu estava escrevendo isso me confundi por causa de um telefone que recebi e daí acabei trocando as coisas. Resposta editada.

Comment: Obrigado, no quesito, estou tb utilizando o targetEntity=Evento.class, é opcional e o que muda ?

Comment: @FelipeJunges O `targetEntity` é desnecessário. Ele só serve para o caso onde você tem `List eventos` ao invés de `List<Evento> eventos`. Ou seja, só é utilizado quando você trabalha com tipos brutos que não têm genéricos (o que não é algo que faça lá muito sentido de se fazer).

Comment: Marcando resposta como respondido :), muito boa sua resposta!

Comment: Aquele link excelente que vc salva como favorito. Valeu cara!