# Como criar um relacionamento @OneToMany no JPA, em 3 tabelas que já existem no banco de dados?

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, hibernate, jpa

Quero criar um relacionamento `@OneToMany` no JPA usando 3 tabelas que já tenho criadas no meu banco de dados (não quero que ele crie as tabelas para mim), as tabelas são `Usuario`, `Perfil` e `UsuarioPerfil`. para isso estou utilizando seguinte trecho de código na minha classe Usuario.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
List<Perfil> perfisPermitidos = new ArrayList<Perfil>();
```

O problema é ao rodar o código é lançada a seguinte Exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 
'nomedomeubanco.Usuario_Perfil' doesn't exist
```

Eu sei que ele faz isso por quê o JPA tenta criar a tabela Usuario_Perfil automaticamente pra usar como tabela intermediária, mas eu quero que ele use a minha tabela `UsuarioPerfil` que já existe no meu banco exatamente para esse fim.

Então dito isso a minha dúvida é como faço para o JPA mapear a tabela `UsuarioPerfil` como tabela de relacionamento e não tentar criar uma tabela default que nesse caso é a tabela `Usuario_Perfil`?

Comment: Para não serem criadas as tabelas você tem que colocar o ddl-auto=none e criar as tabelas manualmente ou de algum outro jeito, usando o liquibase por exemplo. Sobre os relacionamentos veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/234768/113075 essa resposta é muito bem feita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi

Isso depende da estratégia que você usar.
create, create-drop, validate, update

Se estiver usando spring boot por exemplo pode configurar assim

```
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Tem um exemplo no link abaixo

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/dsl/crud-rest-sb2-hibernate-5302424-ptb.html!

Comment: Pois é, mais o que estou precisando é o contrário, na hora de criar o relacionamento eu quero que ele mapeie e use tabelas que já tenho criadas no banco, No meu caso em especifico Ele mapeia `Perfil` e `Usuario` muito bem, o problema é que ele tenta criar uma tabela Usuario_Perfl, por causa das convenções dele, ao invés de utilizar a minha tabela UsuarioPerfil, por isso que eu preciso fazê-lo entender que ele tem que usar a minha tabela e não tentar criar a dele. NOTA: eu desativei a criação automática de tabelas nas configurações.

Comment: Entendi, você precisa usar uma anotação @JoinTable.

Comment: Dá uma olha no link se te atende
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378248/one-to-many-relationship-with-join-tablehttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378248/one-to-many-relationship-with-join-table!

Comment: Isso, era do @JoinTable  que eu estava precisando.