# Como referenciar um dado ja existente na tabela com hibernate

Tags: java, api, hibernate, spring-boot

Estou criando uma api utilizando Java com SpringBoot, e hibernate.
A ideia é salvar convidados no banco de dados, e esses convidados possuem um grupo, não entendo muito as anotações, mas mapeei com @ManyToOne

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "con_convidado")
public class Convidado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Length(max = 20)
    private String nome;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender genero;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Grupo grupo;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Age faixaEtaria;

    public Convidado() {

    }
```

Está tudo funcionando normalmente, porém quando insiro convidados com o mesmo grupo, no banco de dados ele cria uma nova linha, e fica com informações repetidas.

Classe Grupo

```java
@Entity
public class Grupo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;
```

Como fazer para reaproveitar o que ja está na tabela, ou então melhorar o relacionamento entre elas.

Comment: talves esse post te ajude https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234755/diferen%C3%A7as-onetomany-manytomany-manytoone-onetoone, mas me parece que falta a join column.

Comment: Vc esta enviando o grupo com o id existente preenchido?

Comment: Não, estou enviando novamente no corpo da requisição, mas tinha visto em algum lugar que o dado não se repetia

Answer (score -1):

Se sua relação é apenas um único `Convidado` X em um `Grupo` Y e um Grupo pode conter vários Convidados diferentes, logo sua relação é:

Na sua Entidade `Grupo` é que deve conter:

```
@ManyToAOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Convidado convidados;
```

Comment: Na verdade o convidado só pode estar em um grupo. Exemplo: Convidado : Bruno, Grupo : Familia, ele não pode estar em mais nenhum outro, por isso coloquei @ManyToOne

Comment: Então um Convidado só pode estar em um grupo correto ? E um Grupo pode ter vários convidados ? Então a relação seria: @ManyToOne na sua entidade Convidado não acha ?