# Como popular apenas uma parte do objeto com uma query no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-boot, jpql

[Relacionado à essa pergunta que fiz mais cedo sobre Hibernate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/426787/94991)

Estou construindo uma API Restful, e fazendo um join com 2 tabelas. Porém gostaria de trazer somente alguns atributos da minha tabela do join.

**Hoje minha query resulta no seguinte:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Java","schedule":"Monday","teacher":{"id":1,"name":"John","phoneNumber":"35483"}}]
```

**Mas eu gostaria que viesse da seguinte maneira:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Java","schedule":"Monday","teacher":{"name":"John"}}]
```

Ou seja, somente o "name" de "teacher"

***Query:***

```
public interface CoursesRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, Integer>{

@Query("select c, t.name as teste from Course c join c.teacher t ")
public List<Course> findAllCoursesAndTeachers();

}
```

***Classe Teacher***

```
@Entity
public class Teacher {

    @Id
    @Column(name="teacher_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="teacher_name")
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private String name;
    @Column(name="teacher_phone")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher")
    private List<Course> courses;

    public Teacher() {
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /*

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher")
    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }
    */


}
```

***Classe Course***

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @Column(name="course_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="course_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="course_schedule")
    private String schedule;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
    private Teacher teacher;

    public Course() {

    }

    /*
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="teacher_id")
    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
*/

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }

    public void setSchedule(String schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
}
```

Eu tentei usar a `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` mas não surtiu efeito

Answer (score 0):

Você pode especificar a classe que vai ser populada pelo repositório através de projeção.

```
public interface CoursesRepository extends CrudRepository{

@Query("select  new pacote.completo.CustomCourseDTO(c.id, c.name, c.schedule, t.name) from Course c join c.teacher t ")
public List findAllCoursesAndTeachers();

}
```

```
public CustomCourseDTO() {

     private int id;
     private String name;
     private String schedule;
     private TeacherDTO teacher;

    public CustomCourseDTO(int id, String name, String schedule, String teacherName) {

            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.schedule = schedule;
            this.teacher = new Teacher();
            this.teacher.setName(teacherName);
    }
}
```

```
public TeacherDTO() {

        private String name;

        public TeacherDTO(String name) {
                this.name = name;
        }
}
```

Fonte: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos