# É possível ter uma lista como atributo de uma tabela em um banco relacional?

Tags: java, sqlite, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou fazendo um projeto em Java utilizando SQLite como Banco de Dados relacional. Basicamente o projeto é um banco de senhas, onde um Usuário pode ter várias plataformas cadastradas e cada plataforma tendo seu respectivo `Login`.

Segue abaixo como está implementada a classe `User`:

```
public class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Login login;
    private List<Platform> platforms;

    (...)
}
```

A questão é como posso armazenar no banco a lista de plataformas cujo o usuário possui uma conta. Se isso é possível, ou se terei que recorrer a um banco não relacional, por exemplo.

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar uma tabela a parte e definir uma `foreign key`?

Comment: Pelo que me lembro, o SQLite é compatível com MySQL, esse último possui o tipo JSON que pode ser usado para armazenar objetos e listas. Porém no SQL é mais comum (e na maioria das vezes melhor) usar chaves estrangeiras para conectar diferentes tabelas

Comment: Respondendo a primeira pergunta: Sim, eu defini três tabelas — User, Platform e Login, onde eu referencio as duas últimas como chave estrangeira na tabela User. Talvez meu problema seja minha ignorância quanto a aplicação do conceito de cardinalidade em banco de dados.

Comment: Respondendo a segunda: Interessante! Valeu pela dica. Vou dar uma pesquisada sobre o tipo JSON no MySQL, e pelo que me parece, pode até resolver meu problema. A forma ideal como imaginei seria justamente armazenar como JSON, e pensei que só teria em banco de dados não relacionais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso de forma natural. O mais comum é que uma lista seja outra tabela fazendo a correta [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) e [relacionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146425/101) entre elas ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101)).

Em alguns casos a normalização pode não ser necessária (tem que analisar o contexto, pensar em todos os detalhes e necessidades) e aí pode ser interessante gravar tudo na tabela mesmo simulando uma lista em uma coluna normal, provavelmente `varchar`, mas tem que lidar na mão como fazer isto.

Isto é uma forma de fazer no relacional algo não relacional, não precisa usar um banco de dados errado para quase tudo o que precisa por causa de um pequeno detalhe, que é o que muita gente faz hoje em dia.

O SQLite não tem nada próprio porque o objetivo dele é ser simples e flexível, então pode fazer tudo nele, mas nem sempre está pronto, você deve etratar, por exemplo fazer isso como um JSON (um formato que talvez seja complicado demais para algo tão simples). Outros bancos mais sofisticados podem lidar com isso de forma natural e própria sem precisar sair do modelo relacional.

Pode complicar um pouco o fato de ter que gravar um tipo complexo (`Platform`) já que precisa lidar com isso também, e vale para vários outros bancos de dados, poucos possuem recursos para lidar bem com isso e praticamente ninguém usa quando tem (não sei porque, se é desconhecimento, se é porque veem problema nisso). Mas nos comentários diz que tem uma tabela desse tipo então talvez só precise por na lista um `id`s participantes, o que talvez permita ficar tudo do mesmo tamanho e o formato do *array* simulado em um `varchar` seja muito simplificado.

Aproveito para dizer que provavelmente aprendeu [o termo usado de forma equivocada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101) (a não ser que esteja falando do banco de dados, que ele até cabe, ainda que é mais comum as pessoas usarem coluna para isto, o que parece mais correto).

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta e pelos links de conteúdo. Provavelmente eu usei os termos de forma errônea, pois o que quis dizer com "atributo" seria justamente a coluna, como você mencionou. Agradeço pela correção.

Comment: É coluna no DB (mas há uso de atributo), o problema é o uso na classe, o correto é campo, porque atributo é outra coisa (não é culpa sua quase todo mundo ensina errado). Agora você pode votar em tudo no sute também.